# php 8.2.0 reports Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' with php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64

Tags: php

I downloaded php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll

dir php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll
01/10/2023  08:04 AM           290,304 php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll
and copied that to C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
Directory of C:\xampp\php\ext

01/10/2023  08:04 AM           290,304 php_xdebug.dll

Then turned on xdebug in php.ini with
zend_extension = xdebug

But when I run php -i I get

Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\xdebug (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 8.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I picked the wrong dll to download.  Use the Wizard Luke!

I did not use the wizard so I picked php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.0-vs16-nts-x86_64.dll which seemed close enough right?  WRONG!

After 30 minutes of debugging I finally went to the https://xdebug.org/wizard page and that told me to downloaded https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-3.2.0-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll
Once I coped that to the right location and renamed it it worked fine!

Comment: for windows xampp always download Thread Safe (TS).

Comment: Great answer, really helped since I got stuck in exactly the same situation!

Comment: This solved my situation either